# Why are two Entry boxes with the same 'text =' values treated as the same entry box?

Tags: python, variables, tkinter, tkinter-entry

I've asked a question about text being inserted into two entry boxes when it should only be inserted into one. The problem lines of code turned out to be these:

```
MoneyAvailableTextBox = Entry(temp, font=('arial', 14, 'bold'), bg='White', fg = 'Black', bd = 5, width = 10, borderwidth = 4,  justify = CENTER, text = '£')
MoneyAvailableTextBox.grid(row = 1, column = 0, pady = 10)

HeistAwardTextBox = Entry(temp, font=('arial', 14, 'bold'), bg='White', fg = 'Black', bd = 5, width = 10, borderwidth = 4,  justify = CENTER, text = '£')
HeistAwardTextBox.grid(row = 3, column = 0, pady = 10)
```

A friend of mine eventually figured out what the issue was and I answered my own question in case someone else comes across this issue. The issue was that both entry boxes had `text = '£'`. My friend simply changed one of them to have the value `$` and the issue was solved. Deleting them also stops the issue. Neither he nor I am sure why having to entry boxes with the same `text = '£'` makes them be treated as the same entry box.

I've replicated the problem down below. I've simplified the code.

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import*

trialGUI = Tk()
trialGUI.title('Text Boxes')

#This is the text which will be inserted
value1 = 'Hello'
value2 = 'Bye'

#This inserts the text into the entry boxes
def updateStats():
    entryBox1.delete('0', END)
    #This should insert Hello in the first box
    entryBox1.insert(tk.INSERT, value1)
    entryBox2.delete('0', END)
    #This should insert Bye in the second box
    entryBox2.insert(tk.INSERT, value2)

# These are the text boxes
entryBox1 = Entry(trialGUI, text = '£')
entryBox1.grid(row = 0)
entryBox2 = Entry(trialGUI, text = '£')
entryBox2.grid(row = 1)

#Button which when pressed inserts texting into the entry boxes
Button1 = Button(trialGUI, command = updateStats, text = 'Insert Text')
Button1.grid(row = 2)

trialGUI.mainloop()
```

How I said, this issue has been solved. I'm just looking for an explanation why the problem occurs in the first place.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`text` option is the same as `textvariable` option for `Entry` widget.  Since you passed a string `"£"` to it but not an instance of `StringVar`, an instance of `StringVar` will be created with the string as its name implicitly for you.  So both `Entry` widgets are using same `StringVar`.  Therefore changing one of the them will also change the other as they share the same `StringVar`.